# Torch7, how to calculate the number of parameters in a convNet

Tags: parameters, torch, conv-neural-network

I am looking for a way to calculate the number of parameters in a convolutional Neural Network. In particular, I am using the Resnet model in https://github.com/facebook/fb.resnet.torch.
Do you know if there is any function that could calculate the total number of parameters? Do you have other suggestion for doing it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have to go through each layer of your network and count the number of parameters in that layer. Here is a sample function that does that:

```
-- example model to be fed to the function
model = nn.Sequential()
model:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(3,12,1,1))
model:add(nn.Linear(2,3))
model:add(nn.ReLU())

function countParameters(model)
local n_parameters = 0
for i=1, model:size() do
   local params = model:get(i):parameters()
   if params then
     local weights = params[1]
     local biases  = params[2]
     n_parameters  = n_parameters + weights:nElement() + biases:nElement()
   end
end
return n_parameters
end
```

Comment: I thought there was a specific function for doing that, that I was not able to find. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: If you found this answer to be helpful, would you mind marking it as the correct answer? It would increase my reputation.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to train a network in `torch`, you must first extract a vector of its parameters and a vector of gradients w.r.t. these parameters (both are 1D tensors):

```
params, gradParams = net:getParameters()
```

Having it done, it's easy to obtain the number of **learnable** parameters:

```
n_params = params:size(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what have been answered, if you just want to count the number of parameters of the network at layer-level, you'd better to use

```
params, gradParams = net:parameters()
print(#params)
```

instead of `getParameters()`(which returns a flattened long tensor).

The function `parameters()` is very useful when you want to set different learning rates layer-wise.